# How to create a new blog in wordpress?

Tags: customization, blog

I have a wordpress installed and there seems to be many existing blogs. But I can't figure out how to create a new blog.

Is there an top central admin where I can use a gui to create a new blog? The server is at http://wordpress. Some pages say that you can get to it by doing `http://wordpress/wp-admin`, but that link does not work for me (page not found). Instead that only works if I do `http://wordpress/<BLOGNAME>/wp-admin`. Which means I am in a context of a blog. But to create a new one, I have no idea how it's done.

Does anyone know?

Note: I am on wordpress 4.5.2.

So basically, is wordpress something where when you install it, you can just create posts in it, OR is it something where you can then create blogs (or databases) and manage that, and for each one, you can create posts. If it's where you can create blogs, I am trying to figure out how to make a new blog.

Thanks

Comment: where is your server?

Comment: Create new post and name it as blog

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can be used as a single install or as once blog where you create posts for that blog.  Or you can set it up as a multisite installation where you can have a network of blogs.  In a network of blogs, each site (blog) can have it's own theme or plugins.

Follow these instructions to set up a network.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network